# XML file format for describing animation movements?

Tags: animation, svg

Is there an XML file format for describing animation movements?

Is SVG what is currently used? I want to describe 3d information for movements in a format that I can then use in Papervision.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can take a look at [SMIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronized_Multimedia_Integration_Language) which is a XML language for multimedia presentations containing timing, transitions, animations which can be combined with SVG. It's recommended by [W3C](http://www.w3.org/AudioVideo/#Specificat).

If you're interested in 3d animations then you should consider [X3D](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/X3D) which is an XML language for 3d which also contains animations. It's developed by [webd3d](http://www.web3d.org/about/overview/)

But I don't know about usage in papervision.

Answer (score 0):

For X3D take a look at X3Dom
http://x3dom.org

http://github.com/x3dom/x3dom